# Is total displacement equal to the sum of hypotenuses?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, geometry, displacement

[image]

The broken line represents the total displacement (i.e line from furthest vertices of the triangles, and the other dotted lines that create a triangle with the solid lines are the hypotenuses, my question is if the sum of those hypotenuses will yield the magnitude of the displacement vector.

Comment: What is being displaced here?

Comment: this is the supposed to model a path a person has to walk (i.e the object is being displaced from on position to another). does that clarify my question?

Comment: Yes, it does, ta.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Vector addition]

If a walker walks from $A$ to $B$, then from to $C$ to $D$ and then from $D$ to $E$, each walk can be represented by a **vector**, e.g.

$$A \to B \Rightarrow \mathbf{AB}$$

Similarly we have the vectors:

$$\mathbf{BC},\mathbf{CD},\mathbf{DE}$$ These can now be added up so that:
$$\mathbf{AC}=\mathbf{AB}+\mathbf{BC}$$
$$\mathbf{CE}=\mathbf{CD}+\mathbf{DE}$$

Finally:

$$\mathbf{AE}=\mathbf{AC}+\mathbf{CE}$$

This is regardless of whether the triangles are right angled or not.

> my question is if the sum of those hypotenuses will yield the
> magnitude of the displacement vector.

The magnitude, if by magnitude you mean the **[scalar](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/scalar-vector-matrix.html)** of the resultant vector, is *not the sum of the magnitudes of the constituent vectors*. The resultant is like taking a shortcut. Think of a vector's scalar as its *length*.

The resultant vector's magnitude (scalar) is calculated with trigonometry. In the case the vectors are *perpendicular*, say $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, the resultant's $\mathbf{z}$ magnitude $z$ is given by Pythagoras:

$$z^2=u^2+v^2$$

where the non-bolded quantities are scalars.

For non-perpendicular vectors, the extended Pythagoras theorem needs to be used.

Comment: So if I want to find AE (in this example) I have to treat it as its own triangle. thanks.

Comment: Or you can make a direct shortcut and calculate the distance between $A$ and $E$, that is $|AE|$. That's geometry. Upvote?